# How to alter a restassured setting given earlier in the "given()" chain?

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm working on some restassured tests that have a base class method that calls "RestAssured.given()", and adds some default settings.  The derived tests call that method and add onto it.

I'm seeing a situation where a derived class really needs to "edit" the values put into the RequestSpecification in that base class method, specifically to remove a header value.  The derived test needs to set a different value for the header.

You might be thinking that the standard says that the last value set for duplicate headers should be used (although I'm having trouble finding a specific statement to that effect), but unfortunately that doesn't help me at this point, as the codebase I'm working with has an apparent bug, in that it takes the FIRST header value in a set of duplicates, instead of the last one.  I can't just change that right now.

So, in the meantime, I'd like the derived test to remove the earlier setting for the header.  I thought perhaps that a "filter" would do this, but it removes all occurrences of the header, not just the first one.

Comment: Filter is probably the way to go - Can you have the filter remove all occurrences and then add it back with `.header("name", "value")` to the RequestSpecification after you call `.filter()`?

Comment: I already mentioned this in the last paragraph.  ".filter(... remove abc header...).header("abc", value)" results in no "abc" header.

Comment: Then rearchitect the test classes - Have a protected method in the base class add the default header in to maintain backwards compatibility, and override that method in your subclass to do nothing.